# How to merge a remote branch to remote master on Github from local repo?

Tags: git, github, merge

While I was working on **master** branch, I created a branch called **feature**.I switched the branch and I've worked on **feature**.I finished working on it. Now I want to merge these branches(which are remote) from Visual Studio Code using git.

How can i do it properly without detached head problems,etc.? Thanks

Comment: Do you have a clone of the repo on vscode? if so, what's the output of `git status`  on vscode?

Comment: @Bunny Yep.It says: On branch feature
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/feature'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   lib/Counterpage.dart
        modified:   lib/main.dart

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no "remote branches" in Git—well, maybe not, or probably not, or "it depends on what the meaning of *is* is" or other weasel words.  For more on why this is, start with [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)  Note that the word *branch* is rather badly over-used, and the phrase "remote branch" is now in decline, in favor of "remote-tracking branch name", or as I like to call it now, "remote-tracking name", dropping that pesky word *branch* altogether.

What we mean by "branch" in Git, then, is one of these:

- A *branch name* like `master`: this is purely local to your own Git repository.  Some other Git repository may also have a branch name `master`, but that's *their* name.  If your name is Paul or Sarah or Jin or Kimi or whatever, and someone else has the same name, that's not the same *person*.  If someone else's repository has a `master`, that's not the same *branch* (whatever that is), it's just *spelled the same*.
- A series of commits, ending with a particular distinguished commit, which we call the *tip commit* of that series.  We can choose to call this a *branch*, and many people do so, but to work with those commits, you *must have the commits in your own Git repository*.  This means they're local, not remote.

So even a remote-tracking name is local: it's your own Git repository's memory of some *other* Git repository's *branch name*.  [That's what the catch phrase, "everything is local", is about.](https://git-scm.com/)  (This phrase turns up randomly on git-scm.com as you load various pages, so you might not see it right away.)

> Now I want to merge these branches(which are remote) from Visual Studio Code ...

Some people really like IDEs.  I'm not one of them.  I, and others here, would encourage you to try out [git-bash](/questions/tagged/git-bash)—a port of the [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) Unix/Linux CLI to Windows, included with Git-for-Windows.  There are a lot of reasons for this, but many of them boil down to the idea that Git is not a polished solution that does exactly one thing extremely well, and nothing else at all.  Instead, Git is a collection of *tools*, each of which does one thing (with luck, doing it well, although some Git tools are sharper than others).  When you put the whole *collection* of tools together into a *workshop* of sorts, you get something far more flexible and useful than a single polished solution.  If you need to crank out 100 million widgets a day and do nothing else, you want a Widget Maker Mark 500, but you can't use that to fix the toilet seat and re-attach the car's rear-view mirror; the tool set can do both of those.

> [`git status`] says:
>
> ```
> On branch feature
> Your branch is up to date with 'origin/feature'.
> Changes not staged for commit:>
>    (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
>    (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
>          modified: lib/Counterpage.dart
>          modified: lib/main.dart
>
> no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
> ```

If you use the CLI, your next step(s) include running `git add`:

```
git add lib/Counterpart.dart
git add lib/main.dart
```

or just:

```
git add -u
```

(which means *add all updated files*, i.e., everything that just got listed as *not staged for commit*).

You can, if you like, run:

```
git diff
```

first to view the stuff that's "not staged for commit" as a set of changes.  Git doesn't *store* changes—Git stores *snapshots*, with every commit holding a full snapshot of *every* file—but the "show me what changed" tool is a good, sharp, useful tool with only a few dozen oddities to learn.  (Most Git tools have weird knobs and handles sticking out at funny angles that do something extra when you use them, and some of these tools are pretty dull and liable to gouge off some skin or whatever, but `git diff` isn't bad this way.)

Having run `git add`, a `git status` will now list these files as having *changes to be committed*.  You can now run:

```
git commit
```

to create, in your own repository, a new *commit*.  This new commit will be found through *your* branch-name `feature`, on *your* feature branch.  That's not the same as *their* `feature`, which your Git remembers as your `origin/feature`.

Once you have this new commit, you can *send the commit* to GitHub, to *their* `feature`, for instance:

```
git push
```

and you can then raise a GitHub "pull request" (PR) that asks someone else to inspect and/or take your new commit(s) into *their* `master`.  At this point there's just the one commit, and you've sent it to GitHub so that GitHub have the new commit, and remember it as the latest commit on *their* `feature`, so your `feature` and their `feature`—which your software is calling `origin/feature` in your repository—are synchronized again.

You, or they, can then use some of the clicky web buttons on the GitHub web interface to merge that commit to `master` over on GitHub.  Or, you can download the [github-cli](/questions/tagged/github-cli) `gh` command, which lets you do this sort of thing from your bash prompt, by sending GitHub API requests.  All of this lies outside Git proper: this uses GitHub add-ons.  GitHub adds on a lot, because while Git is a pretty OK version control system, it has a complete lack of *access* control: anyone who can access your machine can do anything that can be done, as far as Git is concerned.  Usually you want some kind of control over who can do what to the GitHub copy of the repository.

Comment: Okey thank you very much.How can i merge the branches on Github.Now I have 2 branches in local and on Github.Should I merge these branches first locally and push the commit to the Github?

Comment: That's up to you (and your co-workers). You can do merges locally, or you can do them on GitHub. GitHub's merges are slightly different, and more limited (this has both pluses and minuses).